# How to insert 'NULL' values into PostgreSQL database using Python?

Tags: python, postgresql, null, psycopg2, nonetype

Is there a good practice for entering `NULL` key values to a PostgreSQL database when a variable is `None` in Python?

Running this query:

```
mycursor.execute('INSERT INTO products (user_id, city_id, product_id, quantity, price) VALUES (%i, %i, %i, %i, %f)' %(user_id, city_id, product_id, quantity, price))
```

results in a a `TypeError` exception when `user_id` is `None`.

How can a `NULL` be inserted into the database when a value is `None`, using the `psycopg2` driver?

Comment: Which DB-API adapter are you using?

Comment: by DB-API adapter I suppose you mean the db interface psycopg2. If not, can you be more specific?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

To insert `null` values to the database you have two options:

1. omit that field from your INSERT statement, or
2. use `None`

Also: To guard against SQL-injection you should not use normal string interpolation for your queries.

You should pass two (2) arguments to `execute()`, e.g.:

```
mycursor.execute("""INSERT INTO products 
                    (city_id, product_id, quantity, price) 
                    VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)""", 
                 (city_id, product_id, quantity, price))
```

Alternative #2:

```
user_id = None
mycursor.execute("""INSERT INTO products 
                    (user_id, city_id, product_id, quantity, price) 
                    VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""", 
                 (user_id, city_id, product_id, quantity, price))
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you point me somewhere so I can read why string interpolation in python may lead to sql-injection. This is very interesting and I haven't thought of that.

Comment: You're welcome. This describes well what SQL injection attacks are: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection How does this relate to string interpolation?: Say you receive untrusted input to your program. That input could contain, for example, a `DROP TABLE` command.

Comment: I'm using None for the column value but get an error:

ProgrammingError: column "none" does not exist
LINE 1: ...01.00-ng20', report_date='2016-03-30', ec_enabled=None, ec_s...

Here's the original query that's failing:
UPDATE kw_daily_data_mart SET hostname='ctrlkey.com', users_licensed=7, licensed_users=10, sw_version='kw2016.01.00-ng20', report_date='2016-03-30', ec_enabled=None, ec_server_count=1, config_max_file_version=10, av_enabled=True, location_count=1, sso_enabled=False WHERE customer_id=127892 AND installation_id=3585 AND hostname='ctrlkey.com' RETURNING id

Comment: I am using None, too and I get the same error as @Varun. Same python package psycopg2, v2.6.2. Posgresql v9.6

Comment: Solution also works with an update query. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 9):

With the current psycopg, instead of None, use a variable set to 'NULL'.

```
variable = 'NULL'
insert_query = """insert into my_table values(date'{}',{},{})"""
format_query = insert_query.format('9999-12-31', variable, variable)
curr.execute(format_query)
conn.commit()

>> insert into my_table values(date'9999-12-31',NULL,NULL)
```

Comment: this works for psycopg2 2.8.4, solution with inserting None ends up with the value 'None' in the db, as least for postgres

Comment: If the field being inserted is a text field, using 'NULL', simply inserts those four characters. The answer above (use `None`) is the correct one.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution:

```
text = 'INSERT INTO products (user_id, city_id, product_id, quantity, price) VALUES (%i, %i, %i, %i, %f)' %(user_id, city_id, product_id, quantity, price))

text = text.replace("nan", "null")

mycursor.execute(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach which also is practical with high number of columns:

Let `row` be a list of values to be inserted that may contain `None`. To insert it into PostgreSQL we do as follows

```py
values = ','.join(["'" + str(i) + "'" if i else 'NULL' for i in row])
cursor.execute('insert into myTable VALUES ({});'.format(values))
conn.commit()
```

Comment: Maybe off topic but, I could suggest not to insert to a table without specifying the column names.