# How to insert NULL values into PostgreSQL database using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql

I have list of tuples with data something like this:

```
list1 = [(1100, 'abc', '{"1209": "Y", "1210": "Y"}'), (1100, 'abc', None)]

def insert_sample_data(col_val):
    cur = self.con.cursor()
    sql = """insert into sampletable values {}""".format(col_val)
    cur.execute(sql)
    self.con.commit()
    cur.close()

values1 = ', '.join(map(str, list1))  #bulk insert
insert_sample_data(values1)
```

Table Structure:
ssid int, name varchar, rules jsonb

When I am trying to insert the data but it throws me an error saying "insert column "none" does not exist". How can we load the data into table with 'Null' or 'None'?

I looked at this solution but it does not help in this case [How to insert 'NULL' values into PostgreSQL database using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231491/how-to-insert-null-values-into-postgresql-database-using-python)

Comment: Why does the solution from the linked question not work in this case? Because of the bulk insert? For that you should use [`executemany`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.executemany) or [`execute_batch`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.execute_batch) if speed is important for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @shmee states, you need to use something like `executemany` and parameterize your values instead of using `format`, which is vulnerable to SQL injection.

I would modify your code as follows:

```
def insert_sample_data(self, values): # added self since you are referencing it below
    with self.con.cursor() as cur:
        sql = "insert into sampletable values (%s, %s, %s)" # Use %s for parameters
        cur.executemany(sql, values) # Pass the list of tuples directly
        self.con.commit()

list1 = [(1100, 'abc', '{"1209": "Y", "1210": "Y"}'), (1100, 'abc', None)]
self.insert_sample_data(list1) # pass the list directly
```

Comment: As @shmee said, speed is something really important for my process as there are atleast 100k to 1mil records to be inserted and using `executemany` takes a lot of time. I made few modifications to your code and it worked like a charm. Thanks @Nicarus