# How to pass Null as value to a stored proc to query postgresdb using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, dictionary

I have a stored proc where I need to pass 'null' as value to the query

Here is the dict:

`dict1 = {'name':'apple', 'age':23, 'place':None, 'year':None, 'country': ''}`

Note: The values will always change for respective keys.

I tried this but it does not work for my scenario as he/she are having constant values and are having no empty strings as I do.
[How to insert 'NULL' values into PostgreSQL database using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231491/how-to-insert-null-values-into-postgresql-database-using-python)

I tried to pass the values as None in place null but python is taking it as None not null. Its throwing me an error saying `psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "none" does not exist`

How do I pass dict1 None value as null value to the stored proc query like below using python?

`select * from sampletable."getvalues"('apple', 23, null, null, '')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`None` is correctly converted to `NULL` by `psycopg2`, regardless of whether there are functions in the query or not. This is a proper way to pass a dictionary to `cursor.execute()`:

```
dict1 = {'name':'apple', 'age':23, 'place':None, 'year':None, 'country': ''}
query = cur.mogrify('select * from func(%(name)s, %(age)s, %(place)s, %(year)s, %(country)s)', dict1)
print(query)
```

Output:

```
b"select * from func('apple', 23, NULL, NULL, '')"
```

Comment: Your answer does not work as 'select * from sampletable."getvalues"' would change the query to "select * from sampletable."getvalues"(\'apple',\23\,NULL,NULL,\'\');" using mogrify which totally changes the query.

Comment: `mogrify()` is only to see the query, just replace it with `execute()` to run the query. It's hard to debug the code I cannot see. Please, edit the question and show your python code to have a chance someone could help you.