# What is the suitable value to initialize an empty column of type geometry

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, postgis

i want to set a default value to a geometry column indicates that it is null or empty.for example, a string initially is initialized to null or "" to indicate being void/empty. what is the equivalent to null/empty for geometries.
what is the value to be set to a geometry column inidicates that it is empty. i tried `0` and `""`
but they are not allowed to be inserted in a column of type geometry

Comment: That's what `null` is for

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i am using python , and none is eqivalent to null, however, it is not allowed

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231491/how-to-insert-null-values-into-postgresql-database-using-python

Comment: If `null`/`None` is not allowed then probably your column is defined as `NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a `DEFAULT` to the geometry column with an empty geometry, e.g. for `POINT`:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
  id int,
  geom geometry(point,4326) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'POINT EMPTY'
);
```

It applies also to other geometry types (and their `Z` and `M` extensions as well), e.g.:

```
SELECT 
  'POINT EMPTY'::geometry,
  'POLYGON EMPTY'::geometry,
  'LINESTRING EMPTY'::geometry,
  'MULTILINESTRING EMPTY'::geometry,
  'MULTIPOLYGON EMPTY'::geometry,
  'MULTIPOINT EMPTY'::geometry,
  'POLYHEDRALSURFACE EMPTY'::geometry,
  'TRIANGLE EMPTY'::geometry,
  'TIN EMPTY'::geometry,
  'GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY'::geometry;

-[ RECORD 1 ]----------------------------------------
geometry | 0101000000000000000000F87F000000000000F87F
geometry | 010300000000000000
geometry | 010200000000000000
geometry | 010500000000000000
geometry | 010600000000000000
geometry | 010400000000000000
geometry | 010F00000000000000
geometry | 011100000000000000
geometry | 011000000000000000
geometry | 010700000000000000
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=8d325ff5666f6ac13286f5f68648c5ff)

Comment: you mean that, for polygon, 010300000000000000 is the equivalent to null or empty?