# Handle pg_error on generated columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, generated-columns

I have a table that consists of some PostGIS related data. These data are generated automatically on INSERT or UPDATE.

```sql
ALTER TABLE "Room" ADD COLUMN geolocation geography(Polygon, 4326) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (ST_MakePolygon("polygon"::geometry)) STORED;
```

Sometimes the data provided on the polygon column might not fit the generation function and cause an error. I wanted to handle this error and set a default value when it fail.

-- Last resort options --

1. Creating postgres functions that handle this task but that would disassociate the work from the codebase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you're using `ST_MakePolygon` I assume that the column `"polygon"` contains LINESTRINGs and sometimes they are invalid, which is raising an error in your DDL statement.

What you could do is to create a `CASE` conditional that validates the geometry before trying to create the polygon. For instance, this query  checks if the geometry is valid, if it is a LINESTRING and if its ring is closed before attempting to create the POLYGON. In case it fails, it generates an [`empty polygon`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69940635/2275388) (change it to `NULL` if you want):

```
ALTER TABLE "Room" 
  ADD COLUMN geolocation geography(Polygon, 4326) 
  GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
    CASE 
      WHEN ST_IsValid("polygon") AND 
           GeometryType("polygon")='LINESTRING' AND
           ST_IsClosed("polygon"::geometry) THEN   
        ST_MakePolygon("polygon"::geometry)
      ELSE 
        'POLYGON EMPTY' 
      END) STORED;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=123cb7b0bf2b3768db46cf7546d3ea8f)